# NotSupportedException on OracleDataAdapter.SafeMapping After Migrating to Managed ODP.NET

Tags: oracle, managed, odp.net, notsupportedexception

I recently migrated my code from the native version of ODP.NET to the managed version, and all of a sudden, accessing the **SafeMapping** property on *OracleDataAdapter* gives the following exception:

> System.NotSupportedException occurred
>   Message=Specified method is not supported.
>   Source=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
>   StackTrace:
>   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter.get_SafeMapping()

Having read the purpose of **SafeMapping**, is it possible it simply isn't needed in Managed ODP.NET? Or, is there something I'm doing wrong? Such as, is there now an alternative way of doing what **SafeMapping** did?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to this with the help of Alex Keh, a product manager from Oracle, for Windows and .NET. The solution is to set `OracleDataAdapter.ReturnProviderSpecificTypes` to `true`.

Full discussion can be found [here](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2496563/notsupportedexception-on-oracledataadapter-safemapping-on-managed-odp-net).